# Как зациклить методы в java

Tags: java

Нужно зациклить, чтоб masha.meow() повторялась, пока getWiight не будет меньше 1000.

```
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Cat masha = new Cat();
Cat barsik = new Cat();
Cat chernyshka = new Cat();
Cat nigrutto = new Cat();
Cat vasya = new Cat();

System.out.println(masha.getWeight());
System.out.println(barsik.getWeight());
System.out.println(chernyshka.getWeight());
System.out.println(nigrutto.getWeight());
System.out.println(vasya.getWeight());

masha.meow();



//=====
  public Cat()
    {
        weight = 1500.0 + 3000.0 * Math.random();
        originWeight = weight;
        minWeight = 1000.0;
        maxWeight = 9000.0;

    }
    public void meow()
    {
        weight = weight - 1;
        System.out.println("Meow");
    }

    public void feed(Double amount)
    {
        weight = weight + amount;
    }

    public void drink(Double amount)
    {
        weight = weight + amount;
    }

    public Double getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (masha.getWeight() >= 1000)
  masha.meow();
```